# HBASE backup - how does the java api for export/import work?

Tags: java, hadoop, backup, hbase, bigdata

I am working on backing up a ~70TB HBASE datastore. We have decided to go with single table backup to HDFS (for now). I have come across the Java API for export/import here: http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#export. There is not too much information on Apache's website, and I was wondering if people had any more insight into how the export/import worked? The main question I want answered/confirmed is if the import will work even after a full namenode crash?

Thanks in advance, 
-Aaron

Answer (score 0):

export/import are actually MapReduce jobs and hence will behave like any other MapReduce job. If NN crashes export/import will fail. To be precise, your Mappers/Reducers will get killed. And you will probably encounter **java.net.ConnectException**.